# How do I use the multidimensional array in foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have an array **$cart**:

```
array:1 [
  "product" => array:5 [
      "product_id" => array:2 [
      0 => 2
      1 => 6
    ]
    "product_name" => array:2 [
      0 => "HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)"
      1 => "SAMSUNG 55.88cm (22) Full HD LED TV  (UA22F5100AR, 2 x HDMI, 2 x USB)"
    ]
    "product_description" => array:2 [
      0 => "HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)"
      1 => "SAMSUNG 55.88cm (22) Full HD LED TV  (UA22F5100AR, 2 x HDMI, 2 x USB)"
    ]
    "product_image" => array:2 [
      0 => "1481116344.jpeg"
      1 => "1481180186.jpeg"
    ]
    "product_price" => array:2 [
      0 => 350
      1 => 200
    ]
  ]
]
```

My cart page is something like this:

```
@foreach()
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset('images/150x70.png')}}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <h4><strong>Product Name</strong></h4>
    <h4><small>Product Body</small></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
     <h4><strong>$ Price</strong> x</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>    
@endforeach
```

The Output look Like
[image]

**How do I spam the multidimentional array values in this block of code.** Suppose there are 3 products then there should be 3 rows.

**As the product_name and product_description are different array I am not able to create a foreach where the total rows stays 2 but it spam correct name and body for row.**

Note: I am coding in Laravel framework that is why foreach syntax seems different.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have control over the format of the array being shown here, i would suggest remapping your array so that each element contains a single product rather that the current setup, this should make your life significantly easier

Comment: Agreed, your cart should have an array of products, each with its own properties and oblivious to others. At some point you may have a product that allows the customer to change a color while other products dont, This method will break down pretty quickly with something as simple as that.

Comment: I'm just commenting to further agree with haxxton and deligtedd0d, your products array should be an array of 3 sub arrays which contain all significant information for the specific product. How you've got it now is just going to cause you headaches.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@for()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops) to iterate over array:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart['product']['product_id']); $i++)
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/150x70.png') }}">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
           <h4><strong>{{ $card['product']['product_name'][$i] }}</strong></h4>
           <h4><small>{{ $card['product']['product_description'][$i] }}</small></h4>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
           <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
           <h4><strong>$ {{ $card['product']['product_price'][$i] }}</strong> x</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="quantity">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>    
@endfor
```

Comment: I am getting error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: I forgot to add `$i` index. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! It Works!  you helped me in all my laravel questions :)

Comment: This works, and answers your question exactly. +1. That said, you really should rework your format. Note the difference in readability between this (perfectly working method) and the method I show below. The array and the blade template are much easier to understand at a glance. The difference in maintainability down the road will be well worth your time now ;)

Comment: @DelightedD0D I do agree this seems more complex.

Answer (score 0):

if `product_id` is a consistent field for your `product` array, you can use its length as an iterator count to perform lookups on the other keys. **WARNING** this assumes that ALL keys you're using to output into the template have the same length as `product_id`, and that each index within each key refers to the same product.

You dont appear to have a key for `quantity` so havent populated that field

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i <= count($cart['product']['product_id']); $i++): ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cart['product']['product_image'][$i]; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <h4><strong><?php echo $cart['product']['product_name'][$i]; ?></strong></h4>
        <h4><small><?php echo $cart['product']['product_description'][$i]; ?></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
         <h4><strong>$ <?php echo $cart['product']['product_price'][$i]; ?></strong> x</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-9">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>    
<?php endfor ?>
```

PS. unfortunately i am unfamiliar with Laravel syntax, so this is in standard `PHP`

---

**EDIT**

Because it didnt sit right with me to be using that format i have created a converter function that should turn your array into something more manageable

```
<?php 

function convertCartArray($cart){
    // create new container array
    $products = array();
    // create array of all the keys in the old cart that you wish to convert
    $keys = array('product_id', 'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_image', 'product_price');
    // for each product
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($cart['product']['product_id']); $i++){
        // create a new product array
        $product = array();
        // for each of the keys
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($keys); $j++){
            // convert old cart product detail over to product detail
            $product[$keys[$j]] = $cart['product']$keys[$j][$i];
        }
        // add product to productsArray
        array_push($products, $product);
    }
    // return new products array
    return $products;
}

$productsArray = convertCartArray($cart);

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($productsArray); $i++): ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $productsArray[$i]['product_image']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <h4><strong><?php echo $productsArray[$i]['product_name']; ?></strong></h4>
        <h4><small><?php echo $productsArray[$i]['product_description']; ?></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
         <h4><strong>$ <?php echo $productsArray[$i]['product_price']; ?></strong> x</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-9">
         <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="quantity">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
         <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>    
<?php endfor ?>
```

Comment: The variable $cart consists of product array which has 'product_id'. so when i run this for loop i get error Undefined variable: product

Comment: Basically $cart->product->product id so i cant use product directly any way to handle this?

Comment: @Phoenix, updated to use `$cart['product']` instead of `$product`

Comment: @Phoenix, added new converter function to turn `$cart` into `$products`

Comment: Thanks but someone already provided with an easier method. Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: @Phoenix, i would encourage you to mark a solution as the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

I would reformat the input like this but what you need is `@foreach($products as $product)` `$products` being whatever your current variable is.

If you dont want to change the format of the input (really, I recommend it) use Alexey Mezenin's answer

```
$products = [
    ['id' => '2',
        'name' => 'HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)',
        'description' => 'SAMSUNG 55.88cm (22) Full HD LED TV  (UA22F5100AR, 2 x HDMI, 2 x USB)',
        'image' => '1481116344.jpeg',
        'price' => '350',
    ],
    ['id' => '6',
        'name' => 'HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)HP Core i3 5th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/DOS) X5Q17PA 15-be005TU Notebook  (15.6 inch, Turbo SIlver, 2.19 kg)',
        'description' => 'SAMSUNG 55.88cm (22) Full HD LED TV  (UA22F5100AR, 2 x HDMI, 2 x USB)',
        'image' => '1481116344.jpeg',
        'price' => '200',
    ]
];



@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{asset($product['image'])}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <h4><strong>{{$product['name']}}</strong></h4>
            <h4><small>{{$product['description']}}</small></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <h4><strong>${{$product['price']}}</strong> x</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="quantity">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```